# how can state parameter prevent CSRF attacks

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth2client

In the OAuth2 authorization grant flow, the client application passes a `state` parameter to the `authorize` endpoint. When the state parameter is visible in the browser url, how does state parameter prevent CSRF attacks.